# NULL in C grammar

Tags: c, grammar

I was wondering how NULL could be characterized in a C grammar, will it be a constant?

Comment: Would you expect it to be a variable?

Comment: NULL defined null pointer constant as macro.

Answer (score 7):

`NULL` is a macro object defined in some standard header `<stddef.h>`. On my Debian/Sid/x86-64 system with GCC 4.8 it is defined as follow (lines 394 and following of the compiler specific `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h` header file)

```
 /* A null pointer constant.  */

 #if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
 #undef NULL             /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
 #ifdef __GNUG__
 #define NULL __null
 #else   /* G++ */
 #ifndef __cplusplus
 #define NULL ((void *)0)
 #else   /* C++ */
 #define NULL 0
 #endif  /* C++ */
 #endif  /* G++ */
 #endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
 #undef  __need_NULL
```

BTW, a pointer which has been dereferenced is known to not be the null pointer value. In other words, GCC is permitted to optimize (assuming `p` has been declared as `int *p;`)

```
  int x= *p;
  if (!p) do_very_complex_stuff(); 
  // or: if (p == NULL) do_very_complex_stuff();
```

as simply

```
  int x= *p;
```

at least outside of freestanding programs.

<sup>IIRC, that optimization made a harsh debate between Linus Torvalds and some GCC developers.</sup>

Pedantically the `NULL` pointer (i.e. the null pointer value) is perhaps not required to be all-zero bits, but I don't know any implementation doing that today.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is not part of C grammar. `NULL` is `#define`d in `stddef.h` standard header.

Answer (score 2):

It is macro like this:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

Comment: It is not really always that simple. See my improved answer!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What does it change in case it is C ? The OP is about C not about C++.

Answer (score 2):

C11dr §6.3.2.3  3  NULL is a null pointer constant.

"An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant..." Footnote: "The macro NULL is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant."

Other pointer values *could* also be a "null pointer constant".  They would all compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

In C, NULL is not part of the grammar, it is just a macro.

Comment: No it is not a typedef.

Comment: It's definitely not a typedef, but expression.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a macro.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not part of the C grammar, that's why you have to include a header to avoid compiler warnings (it may depend of your compiler settings)